Confusion regarding the functor sending a group G to the left G actions on some set X
Let X be a set and define $F: Grp^{op} \to Set$ by $G^{op} \to \{$ left $G$ actions on $X$ $\}$. Then the symmetric group $S(X)$ represents $F$. I can not seem to make sense of this. The definition of a functor being representable that I know is the following: A functor $F: C \to D$ is representable if $F \cong R^X$ for some object $X \in Ob(C)$ (where $R^X: C \to D$ is the functor defined by $R^X(Y) = Hom(X,Y)$).
Using this definition, if $F$ were to be representable, there exists some object $Z \in C$ such that for all $G^{op} \in Grp^{op}$ $F(G^{op}) \cong $Hom$(Z,G^{op})$ where $F(G^{op}) = \{$ left $G$ actions on $X$ $\}$. I know that the set of left $G$ actions on $X$ correspond to homomorphisms $G \to S(X)$, however im not sure how to use this fact here.

Basically an action is the data of a group morphism $\alpha: G \to S(X)$ with $g \cdot x = \alpha(g) (x)$ so $F(G)= \hom_{\operatorname{Grp}}(G,S(X))$. The op is there to indicate that this functor is contravariant

This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Please notice that comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, I suggest to post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

Yes @MartinBrandenburg I’ll write answer

The definition of a (left) group action of $G$ onto $X$ is the data of a function $a: G \times X \to X$ verifying the following:

for $g,g' \in G$ and $x \in X$, $a(g,a(g',x)) = a(gg',x)$
$a(e,\bullet)= \operatorname{id}_X$ (thus all $a(g,\bullet)$ are bijective).
For simplicity, we denote $a(g,x)$ by $g \cdot x$.

Now this is data equivalent to a group morphism $\alpha: G \to \mathfrak{S}(X)$, you just need to define $\alpha(g) = a(g,\bullet)$. One can check easily that for $g,g' \in G$, $x \in X
$$\alpha(g) \circ \alpha(g') (x) = a(g,a(g',x)) = a(gg',x) = \alpha(gg')(x).$$
Now this association $a \mapsto \alpha$ is a bijection since its inverse is given by $a (g,x) = \alpha(g)(x)$.
Let us now get back to your question:

The symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}(X)$ represents $F$.

This means that the contra variant functor $\hom_{\operatorname{Grp}}(\bullet,\mathfrak{S}(X))$ is naturally isomorphic to the functor $F$. To prove this we only need to find the natural equivalence $\eta:F \implies \hom_{\operatorname{Grp}}(\bullet,\mathfrak{S}(X))$.
We define for $G \in \operatorname{Grp}$
$$\begin{array}{rrcl}
\eta_G: & F(G) &\to& \hom_{\operatorname{Grp}}(G,\mathfrak{S}(X))\\
& a & \mapsto & \alpha
\end{array}$$
In the same way as before. Now this is clearly bijective, so we only need to check naturality.
Let $\phi:G \to H$ be a group morphism. It gives rise to ${}^t \!\phi:F(H) \to F(G)$ and $\phi^*: \hom_{\operatorname{Grp}}(H,\mathfrak{S}(X)) \to \hom_{\operatorname{Grp}}(G,\mathfrak{S}(X))$ defined by
$$\begin{align*}
{}^t \!\phi(a) (g,x) &= a(\phi(g),x)\\
\phi^* (\alpha) &= \alpha \circ \phi
\end{align*}$$
We get
$$\begin{align*}
n_G \circ {}^t \!\phi (a)(g)(x) 
&= {}^t \!\phi(a)(g,x) \\
& = a(\phi(g),x) \\
&= \eta_H (a)(\phi(g))(x) \\
&= \eta_H (a)\circ \phi (g) (x) \\
&=\phi^* \circ \eta_H (a)(g)(x).
\end{align*}$$
Thus $\eta$ is natural hence we have an isomorphism of contra variant functors
$$\eta:F \implies \hom_{\operatorname{Grp}}(\bullet,\mathfrak{S}(X)).$$

Important remark: elements of $\operatorname{Grp}^{\operatorname{op}}$ are the same as elements of $\operatorname{Grp}$, only the morphism change directions. Here it is necessary to put it this way since these are contra variant functors.
You got confused using $G^{\operatorname{op}}$ instead of $G$.


Hint: don't repeat the proof of the Yoneda Lemma.

@MartinBrandenburg I am well aware of that but I don’t think it is relevant to do so in this context since the main concern is the understanding of basic mechanics of category theory.

@julio_es_sui_glace Thank you very much!
